# I am a man married to an Italian man

Tags: citizenship, marriage, italy

I have been legally married to my male spouse for eight years.
He is Italian, am I able to get an Italian passport?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can acquire Italian citizenship by marriage. The [Consolato Generale d'Italia (San Francisco) web site](https://conssanfrancisco.esteri.it/consolato_sanfrancisco/en/i_servizi/per_i_cittadini/cittadinanza/citizenship-by-marriage.html) gives comprehensive information.

> **Citizenship by marriage/civil union**
>
> CITIZENSHIP BY MARRIAGE TO AN ITALIAN CITIZEN (Law n. 91 February 5th 1992), AND 
>   CITIZENSHIP BY CIVIL UNION TO AN ITALIAN CITIZEN (applications may be submitted beginning 11 FEBRUARY 2017)
>
> The foreign spouse of an Italian citizen may apply for Italian citizenship to the Prefettura after being married for 2 years, if the couple resides in Italy, and to the Italian Consulate after being married for 3 years if the couple resides abroad.
>
> The above periods are reduced by half if the spouses have biological or adopted children.
>   Two basic requirements to be met prior to submitting the application are:
>
> - the marriage must have already been registered at the Town Hall in Italy;
> - the Italian spouse must be registered at the Consulate as an Italian Citizen Residing Abroad (A.I.R.E.).
>
> **DOCUMENTATION TO SUBMIT**
>
> - PRINTED COPY OF APPLICATION FORM (domanda online prepared following registration on the webpage of the Ministry of the Interior - see point 1 below) to be signed in front of Consular officer
> - VALID PASSPORT and DRIVER’S LICENSE (plus copies)
> - ESTRATTO PER RIASSUNTO DAI REGISTRI DI MATRIMONIO issued by the Comune in Italy (NOT OLDER THAN 6 MONTHS) where the marriage was registered (only the original "certificate" will be accepted, not a copy). We suggest that the applicant as a foreign national (and not the Italian spouse) make the request of the "Estratto per riassunto dai registry di matrimonio" to the Italian Comune.
> - PROOF OF RESIDENCY: (utility bill) applicants of other nationalities other than United States must also provide proof of legal residence in the United States (Permanent Resident Card/Green Card)
> - ORIGINAL BIRTH CERTIFICATE – Applicants born in the USA must submit the Long Form legalized with Apostille and translation.
>     Applicants born in countries other than the U.S.A. must comply with the local regulations on the legalization of documents. The certificate must be translated into Italian and certified by the Italian Consulate/Embassy in the Country where the document was issued. For further information, visit Italian consular network.
> - GOOD CONDUCT/CRIMINAL RECORDS (validity 6 months) issued by the Nation of origin and every previous residency starting from the age of 14 . Women should request the certificate to be issued with both maiden and married name
> - [STATEMENT OF NO DIVORCE/SEPARATION](https://conssanfrancisco.esteri.it/consolato_sanfrancisco/resource/doc/2016/05/dichiarazionenodivorzioseparazione.pdf) along with the copy of the Italian passport
> - RECEIPT OF PAYMENT of € 200 fee - As required by the Law n. 94/2009, starting August 8th, 2009 there is a fee of € 200 to be paid by all applicants. The fee of € 200 must be paid through international bank transfer, following these guidelines:
>
> BENEFICIARY: CONTO CORRENTE POSTALE “MINISTERO DELL’INTERNO
>   D.L.C.I. - CITTADINANZA" Piazzale del Viminale, 00184 – ROMA (ITALIA)
>   IBAN CODE : IT54D0760103200000000809020
>   SWIFT CODE: BPPIITRRXXX
>   Eurogiro: PIBPITRA
>   REFERENCE: NAME & LAST NAME “ISTANZA DI CITTADINANZA PER MATRIMONIO”
>
> The application will be evaluated by the Italian Ministry of Interior and will take 730 days (2 years) for the process, from the day in which complete documentation has been submitted.
>
> **HOW TO SUBMIT THE DOCUMENTATION**
>
> Applicants interested in Italian citizenship through marriage will have to submit their application directly online (as listed below). Following the submission of the documentation, the applicant will be contacted for the deposit of the original documents and payment of the other fees.
>
> Appointments for Citizenship by Marriage previously scheduled online MUST BE CANCELLED BY THE APPLICANT.
>
> Although the requirements (documentation) necessary will remain the same (see below), applications will now be submitted on-line by following the steps listed below:
>
> - The applicant will have to register on the following webpage of the Ministry of Interior Affairs: https://cittadinanza.dlci.interno.it
> - After the login, the applicant will find a “CITIZENSHIP” section containing the following subtitles:
> - gestione della domanda
> - visualizza stato della domanda
> - primo accesso alla domanda comunicazioni
>
> (“visualizza stato della domanda” and “primo accesso alla domanda” allow the applicant to check the status of his/her request)
>
> By choosing “gestione della domanda” the applicant will have the possibility to submit his/her application by completing the form: MODELLO AE.
>
> - The applicant must complete the form in its entirety and upload the requested documentation listed on this Consulate’s website:
>
> a. Birth certificate
>   b. Marriage certificate issued by the Municipality in Italy
>   c. Background checks
>   d. Receipt of payment of the 200 Euro fee
>   e. Valid identification (passport)
>
> The applicant may save, modify, cancel or submit the completed application. After reviewing the submitted application the Consulate may:
>
> - accept the request
> - request additional documentation, or request that documents be amended
> - reject the application
>
> The date of submission of the document will be considered the “date of presentation (submission) of the application”. Therefore, the 730 days of processing period will be calculated beginning from this date.
>
> Once the application is accepted, the applicant will be requested to submit to this Consulate all of the original documents and to make the necessary payments.
>
> The above rules do not apply to the automatic acquisition of Italian citizenship through a marriage that occurred before the date of April 27, 1983 (only for foreign women married before that date). Therefore, for marriages that occurred prior to April 27, 1983, applicants must still schedule an appointment through the system “Prenota OnLine”.